# How to redirect urls with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I've got few url that need to be redirected, fore example:
(site_root)/tag/somethig redirect to root, I'm trying with this but not working

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/tag/somethig ./ [R=301,L]
```

Do site root need to be defined before?

My htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php ./ [R=301,L]
```

And I don't what to hardly type domain name, like www.domain.com/xxx, because it on production

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have your .htaccess like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^tag/somethig/?$ / [R=301,L,NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ / [R=301,L,NC]
```

Comment: what does it do (-MultiViews)?

Comment: Please check: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/content-negotiation.html It is better to switch off this option in mod_rewrite  handling.

Comment: Also if this answer helped you solve your problem, please consider marking it as "accepted", so users facing a similar problem in the future will be able to see it easily.